# How do I fix a 'No active admin' SecurityException when publishing my Android app on Google Playstore?

Tags: java, android

i am trying to publish an android app on google playstore. the app is working fine, apparently its already in use. however, these are the issues from playstore.

Error: Detected on 1 device during testing

Stack trace

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}

FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.EnableNetworkLogging
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin, PID: 3294
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin
```

the app is already working fine on all device where its been used, but playstore pending approval gives out the above issues.